# React app served from s3 results in 404 page from edge/IE

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, amazon-s3, react-router, microsoft-edge

So I have a React/Redux application that is being served through Amazon s3 currently.  We have configured s3 to render the index.html page on a 4xx error and serve our bundle.js.  This allowed the react router to be bootstrapped and take over from there.  Until recently this worked without issue.  Now when I try to visit the page in IE or Edge I get the IE or Edge 404 page.

If I turn off the "Show friendly HTTP error messages" option on the IE browser everything works without issue.  From the research I have done this is my theory on what is happening:

When the client hits the requested route the react router has not been bootstrapped yet.  This results in the 404 that has to be rescued by rendering the /index.html page.  When the 404 is returned IE/Edge steps in and renders their own 404 page which prevents the index.html from ever being rendered.

I am kind of at a loss as to how to solve this issue without actually using a full on backend.  I can configure a redirect in the s3 settings to replace the root url with the index.html but this will break all of the sub-routes off of the main route. Is there a way to configure the application so that it works on all major browsers without actually implementing an actual backend?

EDIT:  So I found this article which shows how this issue can be solved using cloudfront by rendering the index on a custom error: https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af.  Does anyone know if this is possible using cloud flare?  I don't actually have the access to cloudflare personally so I am not sure of the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works with "Show friendly HTTP error messages" disabled, then the issue can also be fixed by making your error pages longer. By default, IE will show those pages if it is less than [512 bytes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/08/18/friendly-http-error-pages/).

Answer (score 0):

OK so I discovered:

1) You cannot rescue this error in cloudflare.

2) You can put cloudfront in between S3 and cloudflare and simply implement a custom error rule.

3) Do not use the standard dropdown option when selecting the bucket for cloudfront.  If you give the bucket name when configuring the error rule, cloudfront will treat it like a normal file not a static site and thus it fails to intercept the error.  You have to use the fully qualified url for the bucket.  I hope this saves someone some time.  I lost some sleep over this issue.